# .net validation not working in chrome for other project

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, validation

I have an **old .net project**. .Net version is **4.0**.
asp net validation **works in internet explorer** browser but **not in chrome browser**.

I created a new and empty project to fully understand the problem. asp net validation works in both browsers.

I could not understand what the problem with the old project is, can it be related to web settings?

page is not valid but is postback

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="USTest2.aspx.cs" Inherits="USTest2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"></head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOld" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtOld" runat="server" ValidationGroup="asd" /> 
            <asp:Button Text="submit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="asd" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed a problem when you delete a line from the web config

```
<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />
```

Comment: Tried lot other answers but this realy worked.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net validators are performing client side and server side validations together.

Use Page.IsValid condition to execute your code.

In the button click event handler you need to put

```
if(Page.IsValid)
{}
```

Comment: it's server side.